# How to store card information inside our app from Paypal?

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal

I have been reading Paypal documents for past one week and so.
There are so many things but i did not get any information regarding storing user's card information.
I need something similar like UBER

Answer (score 2):

Please  if you are talking about actual credit card numbers, don't store anything of the sort **inside of your app!** Just don't do it!  For the your sake and everyone else avoid it at all costs!!  There is too much risk involved, and you can find yourself in the middle of a security nightmare, not to mention finding yourself sued.

Instead Paypal has other ways to handle what you want to do.

See this here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/

Paypals Reference Transactions API that returns an unique reference ID allowing you to make future transactions without actually storing card info.

Here is more pertinent information as well https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

Comment: skribe is right your application needs to be PCI compliant to get permission to store these kind of informations. Read up on this here: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/. There are huge fines that VISA/Mastercard can leverage if a fraud breach occurs due to your software, up to hundereds of thousands of dollars per transgression. You should use the service that paypal provides or search another service like stripe: https://stripe.com - Apple won't approve your app if you do it yourself

Comment: Okay so can you tell me how to keep the user logged in, I mean there is some billing agreement. I am making one app where the user can pay from his Paypal account and for doing that i don't want him to enter his credentials for each transaction,

Comment: @Abhishek  I may be misunderstanding your purpose but why don't you use a "cart," where each item is added and then all are paid for at the same time.  If you are wanting it to work where a customer makes a purchase, and then at a later date make another purchase based on the details used in the first, then that is what you use Reference Transactions for.  Here is a guide using them with Express Checkout. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/

Comment: its not like that, Once you completed your ride you will be automatically deducted that much amount from your Paypal account.